# Python, random.randint does not print out

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code down below

I am not sure if of the 22 variables it does not guess the number or have I done something wrong

```
print("pick a number between 1 and 10 and type it down below")
numberone = input()
n1 = random.randint(1,10)
n2 = random.randint(1,10)
n3 = random.randint(1,10)
n4 = random.randint(1,10)
n5 = random.randint(1,10)
n6 = random.randint(1,10)
n7 = random.randint(1,10)
n8 = random.randint(1,10)
n9 = random.randint(1,10)
n10 = random.randint(1,10)
n11 = random.randint(1,10)
n12 = random.randint(1,10)
n13 = random.randint(1,10)
n14 = random.randint(1,10)
n15 = random.randint(1,10)
n16 = random.randint(1,10)
n17 = random.randint(1,10)
n18 = random.randint(1,10)
n19 = random.randint(1,10)
n20 = random.randint(1,10)
n21 = random.randint(1,10)
n22 = random.randint(1,10)
if (n1,n22) == numberone:
  print("i guess your number and it is" + input())
```

if you are reading this, Thank you so much for just attempting to help someone!
you are a good person and are willing to help others

Comment: yes, I am trying to check if numberone is equal to any of the n1-n22

Comment: What @Carcigenicate said. Use a list instead of having 22 variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its very good to explain what you exactly you want to do.

i assume you want to guess the number with 22 attempts and check if any of them got the record.

```
import random

print("pick a number between 1 and 10 and type it down below")
number = int(input())

if not 0 < number < 11:
    print("you should've entered a number between 1 and 10 :(")    

guesses_result = []

for i in range(22):
    guesses_result.append(random.randint(1, 10))

if number in guesses_result:
   print(f"i guess your number and it is {number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `tuple` with `string` data type.
It will be always be False.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to get 22 random numbers, and if it matches an input then print it. If so here are the mistakes you made

1: Instead of making 22 variables, use loops

```
n = 22
for i in range(n):
    guess = random.randint(1, 10)
```

and since you are using a loop you don't need to set a number of guesses, you can just guess until you reach the answer using a while loop.

2: Your if statement. `(n1, n22) == numberone` doesn't mean what you think it means. What it actually does is compare the tuple of n1 and n22 to number 1 which is a tuple of ints to a string so it always returns false.

Finally, here is what a better version of your code should look like

```
from random import randint
number = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10\n> '))
guess = randint(1, 10)

while(guess != number):
    guess = randint(1, 10)

print('Your number is: ' + str(guess))
```